# Keeping Activity when "Don't Keep Activities" is set

Tags: android, android-activity, gallery

i am having an activity that calls the gallery to allow the user to select an image and wait for this image to display for the user.

if the user used the "don't keep activity" option in development options. my application crashes when the user selects the image.

is there an option to keep my activity from being destroyed. if not how can i handle this so that the application does not crash

## code to start gallery

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

## Error

```
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.exm.imageselect/com.exm.imageselect.HomeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1089)
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1084)
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1875)
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1137)
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4475)
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1943)
06-22 15:23:42.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: The "Don't Keep Activity" option is for development and debugging purposes only. You should not expect your app to work flawlessly when any of those development options are checked. Trying to counteract that is largely futile.

Comment: No. This is absolutely standard (but somewhat seldom) behaviour forced all the time. The app must work properly when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

(copy of my answer to similar question - I don't like when there's "see my answer in another question" link)

I switched to Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT with just mime-type and it seems to work better. I guess an HTC bug.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
```